# Why Redirection works well without semicolon, in bash?

Tags: shell, redirect

Redirection dooe not work in these forms.
e.g>

```
~/workspace$ echo foo ; 1>test
foo
~/workspace$ ERRCOMMAND > test ; 2>&1
ERRCOMMAND: command not found
```

but it works in these forms.

```
~/workspace$ echo foo 1>test
~/workspace$ ERRCOMMAND > test 2>&1
```

To me, first commands and following redirection seems to be very discrete actions, so there might be something I do not know.

Could someone tell me about that?

Answer (score 2):

A semicolon is a command separator.

You only need to use it when you have more than one command in a single line.

In the first examples, the redirection apply to a different and in that case also empty command. There is then no reason for the previous command to be affected by something that will happen after its end.

Comment: Indeed; think of semicolon as a synonym for newline.

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon is the "end of a command". you need to tell the command where to redirect to (i.e. redirect before the end of the command).

[this is my terminology: short answer is really as simple as "you just have to"]